# DDOS атака в сети

Tags: ddos

Уже несколько месяцев наблюдаем следующую проблему в сети.
Одно, назовем условно, сетевое устройство, атакует другое сетевое устройство. Атакующим может быть сервер (Windows Server 2012-2019), обычный компьютер (Windows 7 SP1, Windows 10 LTSC), коммутатор доступа. Атакуемым может быть обычный компьютер, сервер, сетевой принтер.

Прилагаю ссылку на скриншоты, сделанные во время атаки с помощью Wireshark.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
https://yadi.sk/d/X4StKI4bErCm3Q

Из скриншотов видно, что атака идет по разным сетевым протоколам, разным портам. При этом с помощью Zabbix фиксируется одинаковый график сетевого траффика Bits sends на ВСЕ порты ВСЕХ коммутаторов.

Если траффик относительно небольшой (до 48Mbs), связь пропадает только с атакующим, если траффик больше 48Mbs, проблемы начинаются во всей сети. Атакуемый при этом почти во всех случаях – выключенный компьютер или компьютер в режиме гибернации.

На всех компьютерах и серверах установлен KES 11 cо свежими обновлениями.
На коммутаторах включена защита от DDOS-атак, защита от петель, настроен Safeguard engine. При атаках с коммутаторов Zabbix получает сообщения «Interface eth1/0/44(): High bandwidth usage >90%». Установлены самые свежие прошивки.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться!

Comment: Больше похоже на проблему с коммутаторами.